# TikZ: how would we construct a bullet?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a block hanging from a string, but at some time later, the block is struck by a bullet.  I am trying to construct a crude bullet but that seems to be harder than I have anticipated.

Thus how do we draw a bullet?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

%  draws block hanging from a string
\newcommand\block{
  \draw (0, 0) -- (0, -1.5cm) -- (-.5cm, -1.5cm) rectangle (.5cm, -2.5cm);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (P1) at (0, -1.5cm);
  
  \block

  \begin{scope}[rotate = 60]
    \coordinate (P2) at (0, -1.5cm);
   
    \block
    % trying to draw a bullet
    %\draw (0, -2cm) -- ++(0, -.25cm) -- ++(; 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Bullets:

[image]

Comment: Is there something wrong with `\textbullet`? (Perhaps *too* crude?)

Comment: @SeanAllred I am speaking of something that resembles a bullet fired from a weapon.

Comment: Yes, but there are many shapes that these bullets can take.  Rifle bullets, shot, pellets, … the list goes on.  Can you upload a sketch of what you're looking for?  (Not a physics guy, myself.)

Comment: @SeanAllred if we used pellets from a shotgun, that would be numerous strikes to the block.  I want just one bullet strike.  See image for bullets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick and crude.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]

\coordinate (A) at (2,3);  % To position the bullet in another fig

\begin{scope}[shift={(A)}, rotate=30]
  \fill[draw=black!80, top color=black!10, bottom color=black!70]
    (0,1) -- (1.5, 1) to [out=0, in=120] (2.5,0.5) 
                      to[out=-120, in=0] (1.5,0) -- (0,0) --cycle;
  \draw[white, draw opacity=0.5] (0,0.1) -- (2.3,0.1);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Bullet]

**Update**: little embellishments.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (2,3);  % To position the bullet in another fig

\begin{scope}[shift={(A)}, rotate=30]
\fill[top color=black!10, bottom color=black!70]
  (0,1) -- (1.5, 1) to [out=0, in=120] (2.5,0.5) to[out=-120, in=0] (1.5,0) -- (0,0) --cycle;
\draw[white, draw opacity=0.5, line cap=round, line width=0.8mm] (0,0.1) -- (1.5,0.1) to[out=0, in=-140] (2.5,0.5)  (0.02,0) -- (0.02,1) (0.2,0) -- (0.2,1);
\draw[black!80, line width=0.4mm]   (0,1) -- (1.5, 1) to [out=0, in=120] (2.5,0.5) to[out=-120, in=0] (1.5,0) -- (0,0) --cycle (0.18,0) -- (0.18,1);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: What is this `out` `in` syntax?  I have never seen it before.

Comment: It is an easy syntax to draw curved paths. You sepecify the angle at which the path departs from its starting point (`out`), and the angle at which it arrives at its end (`in`)

Answer (score 4):

I just imported your bullet graphic and cropped it down to bullet1.jpg, and then wrapped your ballistic pendulum in a `\stackinset`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%  draws block hanging from a string
\newcommand\block{
  \draw (0, 0) -- (0, -1.5cm) -- (-.5cm, -1.5cm) rectangle (.5cm, -2.5cm);}

\begin{document}
\stackinset{r}{3.05cm}{b}{.48cm}%
  {\scalebox{.1}{\rotatebox{-90}{\includegraphics{bullet1}}}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (P1) at (0, -1.5cm);
%
  \block
%
  \begin{scope}[rotate = 60]
    \coordinate (P2) at (0, -1.5cm);
%
    \block
    % trying to draw a bullet
    %\draw (0, -2cm) -- ++(0, -.25cm) -- ++(; 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By defining the bullet placement relative to the right horizontal edge, it will mean than any bullet graphic imported should give the same bullet-tip placement, even if the graphic is of different size/shape.  For example, here it is with bullet2.jpg, with the `\stackinset` parameters the same.

[image]

Also, `\stackinset`s can be nested, if you want your bullet, or a deformed variant of it, to appear in the target block:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
%  draws block hanging from a string
\newcommand\block{
  \draw (0, 0) -- (0, -1.5cm) -- (-.5cm, -1.5cm) rectangle (.5cm, -2.5cm);}

\begin{document}
\stackinset{r}{.65cm}{b}{1.35cm}%
  {\scalebox{.04}{\rotatebox{-30}{\includegraphics{bullet3b}}}}{%
\stackinset{r}{3.05cm}{b}{.48cm}%
  {\scalebox{.04}{\rotatebox{-90}{\includegraphics{bullet3a}}}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (P1) at (0, -1.5cm);
%
  \block
%
  \begin{scope}[rotate = 60]
    \coordinate (P2) at (0, -1.5cm);
%
    \block
    % trying to draw a bullet
    %\draw (0, -2cm) -- ++(0, -.25cm) -- ++(; 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A parameterized head of a bullet with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\bottom#1{\psparametricplot{0}{2}{-#1*t^2+14|t}\psline(1,2)}

\begin{document}
\multido{\r=1.1+.1}{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](0,-3)(15,3)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,linewidth=2pt]
    {
        \bottom{\r}
        \reversepath
        \scale{1 -1}
        \bottom{\r}
        \closepath
    }
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the bullet has the hiccup!